# Errors with c++ pointers to arrays: invalid type argument of unary * (have 'int), lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a function named `transform` which will take in references to the first index of two arrays, `a` and `b`. `b` is an array which contains a list of numbers which determine the order that the array `a` should be rearranged by.

```
void transform(int& a, int& b, const int max_size)
{
    int output[max_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
    {
      output[i] = a + (b+i);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < max_size; j++)
    {
      (a + j) = output[j];
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the program I get the errors invalid type argument of unary * on the command in the first for loop and lvalue required as left operand of assignment for the second for loop. Could someone explain the proper way to use pointers to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(a + j) = output[j];` when you add `j` to `a` you get a temporary value that is the sum of the value of `a` and `j`.  You are not accessing an array element.  Pointer arithmetic only works when you have a pointer, as a reference falls back the the element it refers to.

In order to get it to work you can translate it into a pointer like

```
*(&a + j) = output[j];
```

Which will access the array.  That also means that

```
output[i] = a + (b+i);
```

Needs to become

```
output[i] = *(&a + *(&b+i));
```

All of this though can be avoided by passing the array to the function instead.  That would give you something like

```
void transform(int a[], int b[], const int max_size)
{
    int output[max_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
    {
      output[i] = a[b[i]];
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < max_size; j++)
    {
      a[j] = output[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using std::array as opposed to C-style arrays. Does your advice still hold or is passing an std:array more expensive?

Comment: @cdn If your using `std::array` then just pass the arrays by reference.  The syntax is a little verbose but it's not to bad.  That would look like `template<typename T, std::size_t N> void transform(std::array<T,N>& a, std::array<T, N>& b)` and then you can use `N` for `max_size` since `N` will be the size of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a reference. If you want to write to `a` and operate with pointers arithmetics - you should make a pointer at first.

```
*(&a + j) = output[j]; // this assignment will work
```

But it is an unusual way to do such things in C++. It's more clear to pass pointers to such functions (together with marking them `const` as needed - `b` in your case).

Even better would be to use `std::array` if you work with fixed array size. Or `std::vector` if you want to have size to be determined dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a number and thus the expression

`a+j = output[j]`

is not valid C++.

You probably meant to pass a pointer (`int*`), not a reference to an integer (`int&`).